# Solving a Maze from .txt using C++

Tags: c++, text, fstream, dynamic-arrays, maze

So, I am working on a code that should solve a maze to be given in a .txt file let's say "input.txt" where 1's = blocks and 0's = open paths in a form like this:

```
Maze1
7,6 //Number of rows and columns of the maze: row,column
1,1,1,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,0,1
1,0,0,0,0,1
1,0,1,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1
1 // number of entrances
1,2 // coordinate of an entrance relative to the origin: row, column
```

So I have got some algorithm in my mind, but let's say the "1st" entrance is invalid...

so the output should be like this :

```
Maze1
Entrance: 1,2 Invalid
```

And this should be printed in another .txt file let's say "Output.txt".... but it actually gives me no syntax errors, yet it doesn't write anything to the Output.txt...

Anyways here's my "Incomplete-Code" ... so please help me :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct Stack
{
    int data[30]; //X should be constant
    int top;
}; //Stack

void Push(int a,Stack &S)
{
    S.top++;

    if (S.top>=30) //Remember X should be constant
    {
        cout<<"The stack is full!"<<endl;
        S.top--;
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        S.data[S.top]=a;
    }
} //Push

int Pop(Stack &S)
{
    if (S.top==-1)
    {
        cout<<"The stack is empty!"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        int Temp=S.data[S.top];
        S.data[S.top]=NULL;
        S.top--;
        return Temp;
    }
} //Pop





int main ()
{
    #define false 1;
    #define true 0;
    string line;
    Stack s1 = { NULL, -1 }, s2 = { NULL, -1 };
    int x, y;   //Dimensions of Matrix.
    int z;      //Element Location in Matrix.
    int a;      //Number of Entrance Points.
    int b, c;   //Coordinates of Entrance Points.
    char ch;   //Comma indication.

    ifstream input ("Input.txt");   //Using relative addresses.
    ofstream output ("Output.txt");

    input>>line;
    cout<<"Solution for "<<line<<" : \n \n \n";
    input>>x>>ch>>y;                //Reading the Dimensions of the Matrix.
    cout<<line<<" coordinates are "<<x<<ch<<y<<endl<<endl<<endl;

    int **Maze = new int *[x];      //Creating Dynamic Matrix.
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        Maze[i]= new int [y];
    }


    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)         //Filling the Maze from the .txt
    {
        for (int j=0; j<y; j++)
        {
            input>>z;
            Maze[i][j]=z;
        }
    }


    input>>a;                       //Reading the number of entrances.
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++)  
    {
        input>>b>>ch>>c;            //Reading the entrance coordinates.
        if (Maze[b][c]==1 || b>7 || c>6)   //Checking for the validity of entrance point.
        {
            cout<<"Entrance: "<<b<<ch<<c<<"    is Invalid! \n";
            output<<"Entrance: "<<b<<ch<<c<<"    is Invalid! \n";// WRITE ENTRANCE IS INVALID IN OUTPUT FILE
        }

    }



    output.close();
    input.close();


    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)          //Deleting Maze
    {
        delete[] Maze[i];
    }
    delete[] Maze;



  return 0;
}
```

So where's the mistake ?

Comment: The `Push` and `Pop` functions aren't ever called. Can you pare this down to a minimal example? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Sir, this code is NOT finished yet, I have had other entrances that are valid and I should trace them to get the right path within the stack and push() and pop() functions...
Point is, I wanted to test the code, giving it the first invalid coordinate "that lies on a border" and see if it works, then complete it and see when the "Entrance is Valid" then I use the stack with its functions.

Comment: Fair enough; but it makes it harder for us - and you! - to find the problem if there's extra code cluttering up the example. Even worse, your comment below suggests that you haven't pasted the _actual_ code and sample data you're using. We'll be much more effective if you can provide a minimal example that really matches what you have.

Comment: You are not handling commas when you read in the maze itself. I would work on that before you continue. I mean cout the array and verify that the reading is working before moving on. Reduce the code to just the minimal needed to input if you can not get it to work and ask a new question about that alone.

Comment: Why are you using a stack instead of a tree?  For example, at the location after the entrance, there are two paths to explore.  Also, how are you remembering the path?

Comment: Sir, I'm not using the stack yet, I'll use it if the "Entrance" is VALID.
The text has 3 entrances, and as you see I chose the first one which is invalid ... I have the original text and the original output text also, and what I wrote up there is the first part of the output, so it should match .... I have 2 other "Entrance points" but I only wanted to check if the part that I wrote is working on not.

So the problem here is with filling the Matrix with the 1's and 0's ignoring the commas .. could you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C++ are 0-indexed - that is, `Maze[1][2]` is the cell in the second row, third column. Either number your entrance cell like that in the input file, or subtract 1 from each co-ord in the code.

Also, when parsing the maze itself, you don't seem to be taking account of the commas.

Comment: About the coordinate, I took into the account that they're 0-indexed, and actually the solution I'm given is right, it should be invalid.

Yes, I didn't take the commas into the account, because the maze should be filled with integers only, 1's or 0's, so I tried to read "z" as to get integers and ignore commas.

I'm quiet not sure about the way I filled the dynamic matrix, so if you have anyway you could help me with to fill it correctly, please tell me.